Turkish National Geodetic Network parameters, Turkish National Vertical Control Network (TUDKA-99) & Turkish Fundamental GPS Network 1999A (TUTGA-99A)
I have a shapefile with the GCS_TUREF coordinate system. The client's requirement is to align the GIS files with the parameters of the Turkish National Geodetic Network, specifically the Turkish National Vertical Control Network (TUDKA-99) and Turkish Fundamental GPS Network 1999A (TUTGA-99A). Additionally, all necessary correlations regarding regional sea level corrections must comply with the requirements of the Turkish National Sea Level Monitoring Network (TUDES).
Can you you provide details on aligning the GIS shapefiles with the Turkish National Vertical Control Network (TUDKA-99)/Turkish Fundamental GPS Network 1999A (TUTGA-99A) in ArcMap?
